# unexpected error in unordered_map iterator comparison

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a simple map std::map<string, my_namespace::MyType>, I am using c++11 so I replaced it with unordered_map for performance reasons. I got the following error when comparing an iterator with end().

```
auto cit = str_map_.find(str);
if (cit != str_map_.end()) {
   ...
}
```

In instantiation of 'bool my_namespace::operator!=(const T1&, const T2&) [with T1 = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string, my_namespace::MyType, false, true>; T2 = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair\ <const std::__cxx11::basic_string, my_namespace::MyType, false, true>]': no matching function ...

I debugged it down to my rather creative comparison operators for my_namespace::MyType:

```
template <class T>
struct MyType {
    T* mt_;
};

struct MyTempClass {
    std::string mtc_;

    static int Compare(MyType<MyTempClass> const& lhs, MyType<MyTempClass> const& rhs) {
        return lhs.mt_->mtc_.compare(rhs.mt_->mtc_);
    }

    static int Compare(std::string const& lhs, MyType<MyTempClass> const& rhs) {
        return lhs.compare(rhs.mt_->mtc_);
    }

    static int Compare(MyType<MyTempClass> const& lhs, std::string const& rhs) {
        return lhs.mt_->mtc_.compare(rhs);
    }
};

template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator !=(T1 const& lhs, T2 const& rhs) {
    int res = MyTempClass::Compare(lhs, rhs);
    return (res != 0);
}

template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator ==(T1 const& lhs, T2 const& rhs) {
    int res = MyTempClass::Compare(lhs, rhs);
    return (res != 0);
}

static std::unordered_map<std::string, MyType<MyTempClass>> my_map;
```

But I am still puzzled why it did happen: the same code works fine with a plain map, and values type should not be involved in iterator comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

You defined an `operator!=` overload that takes any type as an argument. That overload is in the same namespace as the type `MyType`. Therefore, it can potentially be found via ADL.

As the error message indicates, the `std::unordered_map` iterator used by the standard library is a class template specialization, specialized on the `std::unordered_map` template arguments. As such, when you compare iterators with `!=`, ADL is performed on the arguments and the namespaces searched by ADL also include the namespaces of type template arguments of the types of the arguments. Therefore, your `operator!=` overload in the namespace of `MyType` will also be found and participate in overload resolution.

Assuming you are using libstdc++ as standard library implementation based on the error message, you can have a look at [it's implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/hashtable_policy.h) of the `operator!=` for hash table iterators and you will see that it uses a base class for these iterators, and defines the comparison operators for references to the base class objects.

As a consequence, the standard overload for the iterator comparison requires a derived-to-base reference conversion in its arguments, while your overload does not.

Therefore your overload is better and will be chosen to do the `cit != str_map_.end()` comparison. Your overload tries to pass the arguments `MyTempClass::Compare` which clearly doesn't work, because these functions don't expect `std::unordered_map` iterators.

---

The solution is not to overload operators for pairs of types that do not depend on user-defined types. Restrict your overloads to your own types:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator !=(MyType<T1> const& lhs, T2 const& rhs) {
    int res = MyTempClass::Compare(lhs, rhs);
    return (res != 0);
}

template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator !=(T1 const& lhs, MyType<T2> const& rhs) {
    int res = MyTempClass::Compare(lhs, rhs);
    return (res != 0);
}
```

(equivalently for `operator==`).

---

As far as I know, it is not forbidden to overload the operators for standard library type pairs, but I also don't think that the standard library is required to account for conflicts this generates as in your code.

With `std::map` the standard library implementation might have chosen a different way of implementing the iterator comparison, which made it a better fit in overload resolution or avoided that ADL finds your overload by not making the iterator a template specialized on the key/value type.

Comment: Thank you, but I really surprised that value type is playing any part in iterator comparisons.

Comment: @zzz777 It doesn't. The short version of my explanation is that you just replaced the meaning of `!=` by declaring a `operator!=` overload that claims to accept any type. This is more obvious if you use the expression containing `!=` in the same namespace in which the overload is declared. In your case it is just a bit roundabout because of C++ argument dependent lookup rules.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying. I had this issue resolved, thank you. But I still do not get it, I did not override anything for the keys, the key is still simple std::string whatever is the value it should have no effect on maps??? Say I have values that are not comparable at all or have some out of whack ordering, I believe that maps with these values should still work?

Comment: @zzz777 The key and value type don't really matter. It only matters that your custom type appears in them as template argument. The comparison `cit != str_map_.end()` compares iterators, not keys. The comparison _should_ choose an `operator!=` overload defined in the standard library for them. But normal overload resolution applies to _every_ use of an operator. C++ overload resolution has the _argument dependent lookup_ rule (ADL), which says that also overloads, not usually found by direct name lookup, but defined in namespaces associated with the types of the arguments are found.

Comment: Your overload is found that way (details in the answer) and happens to be a better fit in overload resolution. Instead of using the `operator!=` overload defined by the standard library that _should_ be used for iterators your function is called, which is obviously nonsense. This could have happened comparing any types from the standard library that take your custom type as template argument. It is not specific to `std::unordered_map` or its iterators or anything.

Comment: @zzz777 C++ argument dependent lookup rules are quite unintuitive sometimes and result in subtle bugs like this. If you define a type and an operator overload for that type direcly in the same namespace there is always the possibility that ADL finds that operator overload if you compare types that are related to your custom type. That doesn't mean only your custom type (for which this is desired behavior), but also types which dependent on your custom type via template arguments.

Comment: As you have seen that is dangerous and why you shouldn't define operator overloads that accept arguments not containing your custom type.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, defining the full matrix of type-specific operators meant a lot of typing (36 operators), just tried to avoid it in the hope that the operator lookup will fail on trying to fit a call to MyType::Compare() function. Apparently, this idea was not so good.

Comment: @zzz777 Alternatively to the modification I mentioned in my answer you could have also used `std::enable_if` or a `requires` clause (C++20) to constrain the template. I didn't mention it, since the implementation is a bit less obvious, but it might reduce duplication of the operators.